# What's the purpose of netrc.macros in the netrc module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand the purpose of this instance variable.
When I look at it, it's just an empty dict.
What was the reason behind having such a variable and leaving it empty?
Wouldn't it be better just define a dict if needed?

Comment: Did you look at the docs?

Comment: Yes. the problem is it just doesn't seem to be essential at all.